# Custom msg for diference package

Tags: rosmsg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am doing the communication between two computer, and  I use 2 difference package name.

How can I create and general and custom msg to comunicate between 2 node.

For Example in Package A, I create msg.

Position.msg

```
float64 x
float64 y
float64 x
```

and the msg type will be A/Position

and in Package B, I create msg.

Position.msg

```
float64 x
float64 y
float64 x
```

and the msg type will be B/Position

:(
Thanks all

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10504/custom-msg-for-diference-package/) by [embeddedheaven](https://answers.ros.org/users/169/embeddedheaven/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2011-07-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-07-06**:
If you want the message like the ones you defined, geometry_msgs/Point already does that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I assume that you have all packages in one single repository and both computers have it checked out. Then the following should work:
B could either use A's message definition or A could use B's message definition. However, it is pretty common in ROS to create a separate package C that only contains the message and no code. All you need to do is to create that package C, put the message file into the msg/ sub-directory and update your CMakeLists.txt to build that message. Then edit A's manifest and let it depend on C, edit B's manifest respectively. In A and B, instead of including A/Position.h or B/Position.h, include C/Position.h.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2011-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7